# Cannot overwrite default django database settings

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I've got a problem with Django DATABASES setting in settings.py.
I'm using Python 3.4.3, Django 1.10.5 and psycopg 2.6.1

if my code looks like

```
        DATABASES = { 
            'default':{
                  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
                        'NAME': ' dbname',
                        'USER': 'postgres',
                        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
                        'HOST': 'localhost',
                        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and i run manage.py diffsettings  in DATABASE section there are some default settings:

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'USER': '', 'HOST': '', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'NAME': '', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TEST': {'MIRROR': None, 'CHARSET': None, 'NAME': None, 'COLLATION': None}, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'PASSWORD': '', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'PORT': ''}}
```

but when I change 'default' to 'db' (or any other name)

```
       DATABASES = { 
            'db':{
                  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
                        'NAME': ' dbname',
                        'USER': 'postgres',
                        'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
                        'HOST': 'localhost',
                        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

the manage.py diffsettings 'knows'  the database db:

```
DATABASES = {'db': {'NAME': 'dbname', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'PORT': '5432', 'PASSWORD': 'dbpass', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'USER': 'postgres'}, 'default': {'OPTIONS': {}, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'HOST': '', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'PASSWORD': '', 'USER': '', 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'NAME': '', 'PORT': '', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'TEST': {'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'CHARSET': None}}}
```

What should I to to use my database as a default and don't have to use DATABASE_ROUTERS ?

Comment: are you sure you are not overwriting your settings somewhere ? when you dont want to use routers, you have to specify your db as default

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the default at all?

Comment: Oh.. it was easy as that...
on the bottom of the page I've got settings specified for Heroku 


#HEROKU
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

and that was overwriting my settings... I don't know why this code is there, i have to find another way to set database for Heroku.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment in the question above, I'm assuming that you're trying to set up Django in a Heroku instance.

If you're using Heroku's starter template, you're going to see an overwrite to the DATABASES variable. This is because Heroku uses the library *dj_database_url* to get the environment path of the database that was deployed with your Heroku app. So Django updates the default database to use it. This is relevant when you want to deploy your Django app to the Heroku instance.

In case you want to use your app in your local environment (your machine), you just need to comment those two lines:

```
# db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
# DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

But remember to comment out those lines again when uploading your code to Heroku.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was uploading my project to Heroku, but previously I don't have to care about DATABASES variable - somehow it choose right definition regarding to running environment (local, Heroku). I can't remember erasing it, but deffinetly I have to change it in a bad way.
Thanks for your comment.